# PHP Parse JSON Array Imported from xlsx

Tags: php, json, parsing

I know there are some post concerning parsing xlsx but not really any help. I have a workbook with approx 30 sheets. I have exported the information to a json array. The array looks like the following:

```
   {
  "1" : [
{
  "FIRST NAME" : "Anthony",
  "LAST NAME" : "Hopkins",
   "SERIAL NUMBER 4" : "",
  "ACCOUNT STATUS" : 1,
 },
{
  "FIRST NAME" : "Bob",
  "LAST NAME" : "Dillion",
  "SERIAL NUMBER 4" : "",
  "ACCOUNT STATUS" : 1,
 },
```

The "1" is the sheet name with the elements of the sheet making up the content of the array. In the file exported at the end of "1", the next sheet name "2" is used and so forth til the end of the workbook. I didn't name the sheets somebody else did. I can't seem to parse this. I tried the following

```
   ob_start();
   include ('myfile.json');
   ob_end_clean();

     for($i=1; $i<31; $i++){
         $index="''".$i."''";
         echo $index."<br>";
           foreach($index as $items){
                  ehco $items['First Name'] as $fn){

                 }
             }
```

Any help with this greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Climero pointing me to decode. Using json-decode and the following

```
      foreach($json_array as $item){
      foreach($item as $root){
      foreach($root as $key=>$value){

       if($key=="FIRST NAME"){
         echo $value."<br>";
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

I was able to get on the right track.
Thanks again